# SoundCLI gem fails

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, debian, alsa

I am trying to run the [soundCLI](https://github.com/rekado/soundCLI) gem, but it fails with:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soundcli-0.0.5/lib/soundcli/player.rb: line 158
   (null)-WARNING **:Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=57ae80824714b7b337db9bbc5115ac19 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
AL lib: alsa_open_playback: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
The autoaudiosink element is not working.
gstplaysink.c(1906): gen_audio_chain (): /GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink0
```

I am a newbie with ruby :), so I'd appreciate any help. I am running Debian on a Raspberry Pi if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was not part of the `audio` group, so I ran the following command: `sudo adduser <username> audio` , restarted and voilà!